# Improve speed execution of MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, select, query-performance

I have 2 MySQL tables with several millions of rows and I'm trying to perform a query selection for get specific data column from both tables. Despite my first good expectations the execution of the query selection takes several seconds (around 5 seconds) also with an index applied on the WHERE condition.

#### Create statement for the 2 MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
  `T1_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `T1_val1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `T1_val2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `T1_val3` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `T1_val4` datetime NOT NULL, 
  `T1_val5` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
  `T1_val6` float NOT NULL,
  `T1_val7` datetime NOT NULL,
  `T1_val8` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `T1_val9` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
  `T1_val10` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`T1_id`),
  KEY `T1_val4` (`T1_val4`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53885653 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `T2` (
  `T2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `T2_val1` float NOT NULL,
  `T2_val2` float NOT NULL,
  `T2_val3` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`T2_id`),
  KEY `T2_val3` (`T2_val3`),
  KEY `T2_val1_2` (`T2_val1`,`T2_val2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see both tables have an **AI primary key** and **foreign key** that matches as `one-to-one relationship` between them (`T1_id` and `T2_id`). And we have an **index** applied on `T1` for `T1_val4` that is in a **datetime format**.

#### The selection query

```
SELECT 
      T1_val5, 
      T2_val1, 
      T2_val2, 
      T2_val3, 
      T1_val9, 
      count(T2_val1) as cnt, 
      T1_val4
   FROM 
      T1 USE INDEX (T1_val4)
         INNER JOIN T2 
            ON T1.T1_id = T2.T2_id 
   WHERE 
      T1_val4 BETWEEN '2016-02-18 15:00:00' 
                  AND '2016-02-18 16:59:59'
   GROUP BY 
      T2_val1, 
      T2_val2, 
      T2_val3, 
      T1_val9, 
      T1_val5
   order by 
      T1_val4 ASC;
```

As you can notice, I have specified a HINT for the index in order to tell to MySQL to use that specific index for the datetime column. Actually if I extend the datetime range in the WHERE condition to several hours well.. for example `BETWEEN '2016-02-18 15:00:00' AND '2016-02-18 23:59:59'` the execution time grows up till 50/100 seconds. Probably I'm missing something in the logic.

#### The EXPLAIN output

```
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|   ID  |   SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE   |   TYPE    |   POSSIBLE_KEYS   |   KEY     |   KEY_LEN     |   REF     |   ROWS    |       EXTRA                                                |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE      |   T1      |   range   |   T1_val4         |   T1_val4 |      5        |   NULL    |   10670   |   "Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort" |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE      |   T2      |   eq_ref  |   PRIMARY         |   PRIMARY |      4        |   T1_id   |   1       |     NULL                                                   |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### The EXPLAIN output updated with compound index

**(As suggested from @O. Jones)**

```
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   ID  |   SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE   |   TYPE    |   POSSIBLE_KEYS              |   KEY     |   KEY_LEN     |   REF     |   ROWS    |       EXTRA                                                   |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE      |   T1      |   range   |   "PRIMARY,ix_rlf"           |   ix_rlf  |      5        |   NULL    |   10906   |   "Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort" |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE      |   T2      |   eq_ref  |   "PRIMARY,ix_cc"            |   PRIMARY |      4        |   T1_id   |   1       |     NULL                                                      |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**ix_rlf** is the compound index of `T1_val4`, `T1_val9`, `T1_val5`and **ix_cc** is the compound index suggested from @Tom Shir for T2 made of `T2_id`, `T2_val1`, `T2_val2`, `T2_val3`.

#### Query execution plan visual schema

**(considering 2 HOURS as interval, and in this case the result of the query it's around 6632 rows and 6/7 seconds as execution time)**

[image: query execution plan schema]

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Please [edit] your question to show us the `EXPLAIN` output and other relevant information. By the way your `GROUP BY` clause also needs to mention `T1_val4`, your datestamp column.

Comment: You're right! Just give me some minutes and I'll add the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: What's the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: For `innodb_buffer_pool_size` it's 6123683840

Comment: Note that `ix_cc` was not picked.  Anyway, `PRIMARY` is nearly as good.

Comment: So, it means that probably `PRIMARY` is better than the compound index `ix_cc` created for `T2`? Cause I didn't specify a HINT cause other users suggested me to remove it, cause MySQL already knows which is the best combination to apply.

Answer (score 1):

By leaving out `T1_val4` from your `GROUP BY` clause you're taking advantage of MySQL's nonstandard extension. You may be getting undesired results. Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Generally, using `BETWEEN` for datetime-like columns is a bad idea because it handles range-end conditions poorly.  If I were you I'd write this

```
WHERE T1_val4 >= '2016-02-18 15:00:00' AND T1_val4 < '2016-02-18 17:00:00'
```

You have the right idea indexing your datestamp column. You might try using a [compound covering index](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) instead of your simple datestamp index. It looks like your query is pulling about ten thousand rows from `T1`, so a compound covering index will help.  Put all the columns you need in the index, with the range scan column first. That means MySQL can satisfy the whole query by doing the index range scan, which is faster. The index should be on these columns.

```
 T1_val4, T1_val9, T1_val5
```

Because you're using InnoDB, you don't have to include the primary key in your compound index.

This should be a little faster. But, still, you're asking MySQL to retrieve and index ten thousand rows, and that is actually real work.

Comment: Thank you @O. Jones for your reply. I was reading both the 2 answers that I have received. Can you explain me exactly why index only the `T1` should be better than indexing also the `T2` as @Tom Shir wrote? In terms of performances should be slightly different?

Comment: I have tried to add the compound index that you suggested me for `T1`, I have replaced the BETWEEN condition and I have also included in group by the `T1_val4`. But after these changes the execution performance has remain the same.

Comment: I didn't suggest indexing `T2` because your `EXPLAIN` output said your query was only looking at a few rows, plus you're accessing it via its primary key and have no `WHERE` conditions on it. What does `EXPLAIN` tell you after you add the compound index?

Comment: I have added just right now the EXPLAIN output after add the index compound. The output seems slightly different, it takes the compound index I think. But as I said the performance is not positively affected.

Comment: I assume you took out the `USE INDEX`. Right? Also, doublecheck you created the index correctly. EXPLAIN says the index length is 5, which is the same as your first EXPLAIN. If that's all true, then you're pretty close to ideal performance. Don't forget you're asking MySQL to process 10K rows.

Comment: Yes! I have already removed the `USE INDEX` cause probably MySQL already knows what's the best index to apply.

Comment: Actually if the output result of the query is around **3500 rows**, the query takes around **6 seconds**. I should assume that this is the best configuration that I can obtain? Yes, I have correctly added the compound index in the order that you suggest me: `T1_val4`, `T1_val9`, `T1_val5`. I think that eventually other compound index added in `T2` should not negatively affect the performances in this case.

Comment: Your output result is 3.5k rows, but the input to the GROUP BY is more than that according to EXPLAIN.

Comment: So, in your opinion there is no way to improve the actual performance as execution?

Comment: Even better:  `WHERE T1_val4 >= '2016-02-18 15:00:00' AND T1_val4 < '2016-02-18 15:00:00' + INTERVAL 2 HOUR`

Comment: @RickJames actually with `+ INTERVAL 2 HOUR` the execution time of the selection query has been incredibly reduced at around **2.8 seconds** for 3500 rows!

Comment: I have also updated the question with the image of the query execution plan for **2 hours** as interval (that is around **6632 rows** as output result, and around **7/8 seconds** as execution time). Maybe it could be useful for understand better the situation if we have some chances of improve yet or not.

Comment: @UgoL - the `INTERVAL` pattern does not help performance -- something else must have happened simultaneously.  (A 10x speedup can often be traced to caching.)

Answer (score 1):

This is your query with table prefixes:

```
SELECT
        T1.T1_val5,
        T2.T2_val1,
        T2.T2_val2,
        T2.T2_val3,
        T1.T1_val9,
        COUNT(T2.T2_val1) AS cnt,
        T1.T1_val4 
    FROM
        T1 
    INNER JOIN
        T2.T2 
            ON T1.T1_id = T2.T2_id 
    WHERE
        T1.T1_val4 BETWEEN '2016-02-18 15:00:00' AND '2016-02-18 16:59:59' 
    GROUP BY
        T2.T2_val1,
        T2.T2_val2,
        T2.T2_val3,
        T1.T1_val9,
        T1.T1_val5 
    ORDER BY
        T1.T1_val4 ASC
```

I believe you can improve its performance by using the correct indexes.
I ran your query through an [SQL query optimizer](https://www.eversql.com) I'm using for my own queries, which recommended to use these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `T1` ADD INDEX `T1_index_1` (`T1_id`, `T1_val4`);
ALTER TABLE `T2` ADD INDEX `T2_index_1` (`T2_id`, `T2_val1`, `T2_val2`, `T2_val3`);
```

Also, please post the explain plan, as it can help better understand which indexes are currently used by MySQL.

Another recommendation - remove the hint you added. Usually, MySQL will know how to optimize the query better than we do.

Comment: fwiw, for an index to optimize the range scan on `T1_val4` that column necessarily must come first in the index's list of columns. Also, in InnoDB, indexes with the primary key coming first are redundant with the structure of the table itself.

Comment: Can you please explain why the range column should be first (and maybe include a reference link)? If that's the case, so it means you can't create an index where both a column from the ON clause and a range scan will be used for optimizing the same query?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good resource for understanding query optimization. MySQL indexes have an ordered BTREE structure. So when a query calls for a contiguous range of values in some column, if that column comes first the query planner can random access the index to the first eligible entry, then scan sequentially to the last one.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone through those articles in the past and saw that this page specifies to index for equality first, and only then for ranges. http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates. Is it different for cases when the equality is col1=col2 (like usually happens in a join ON clause) and not col1=const?